# Apply boxplot function within nests

Tags: r

I have a simple nest that groups by `colour` for `iris` then I want to apply a boxplot and grab the outliers from the dataset after it has been grouped.

For example:

```
bxplt <- function(DATA, X, Y){
  bxp <- boxplot(data = DATA, {{Y}}~{{X}}, outcex=2)
  cBXP <- bxp[4:5] %>% do.call(cbind.data.frame, bxp)
  return(xBXP)
}
upIris <- iris %>% mutate(colour = rep(c('Red', 'Blue', 'Green'), 50))
upIris %>% group_by(colour) %>% nest(.) %>% mutate(extra_data = map(data, ~ .x %>% bxplt(., Species, Sepal.Length)))
```

This gives the following error:

> Error in `mutate()`:
> ! Problem while computing `extra_data = map(data, ~.x %>% bxplt(., Species, Sepal.Length))`.
> ℹ The error occurred in group 1: colour = "Blue".
> Caused by error:
> ! object 'Sepal.Length' not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ensym()` and `inject()` from `rlang`

```
library(rlang)
bxplt <- function(DATA, X, Y){
  y <- ensym(Y); x <- ensym(X)
  bxp <- inject(boxplot(!!y ~ !!x,data = DATA, outcex=2))
  do.call(cbind.data.frame, bxp[4:5])
}
```

Now, apply that function using `map()`:

```
iris %>%
  mutate(colour = rep(c('Red', 'Blue', 'Green'), 50)) %>% 
  group_by(colour) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(extra_data = map(data, ~bxplt(.x, Species, Sepal.Length)))
```

Output:

```
  colour data              extra_data  
  <chr>  <list>            <list>      
1 Red    <tibble [50 x 5]> <df [0 x 2]>
2 Blue   <tibble [50 x 5]> <df [8 x 2]>
3 Green  <tibble [50 x 5]> <df [1 x 2]>
```

Comment: I had tried using the double bang and ensym this way ```!!ensym(Y)``` before this and always got this error: ```Caused by error in `!ensym(Y)`:
! invalid argument type``` however, it seems your approach works. Although, `inject` would mean that the next argument `cBXP <- bxp[4:5] %>% do.call(cbind.data.frame, bxp)` is unuseable

Comment: see edit.. I was focused on your bang-bang issue.

Comment: Although this worked ```bxr <- (rlang::inject(boxplot(!!y ~ !!x,data = DATA, outcex=2)))[4:5]``` then I could do the rest

Comment: `inject` is new to me thank you for sharing it!

Comment: its a useful tool for injecting bang-bang or embrace operators in non tidyverse functions, like `boxplot`